# Multiply an entire column to x number

Tags: excel, vba

[Screenshot#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qwcf.png)

So i have column "B" , i have to multiply an entire column to "x" number. For example it will be "10".

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() //= Multiply [screenshot#3]
Range("C2:C10").Value = Range("B2:B10").Value * 10
End Sub
```

I am getting error :[Screenshot#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmNRF.png)

Here is how looks my userform:
[Screenshot#3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq5FW.png)

Comment: `Range("B2:B10").Value` is a 2D Variant array... you can't multiply an array by 10. You could use `Copy/PasteSpecial Multiply`. Or loop. Or `Evaluate` maybe.

Comment: I don't understand what u means

Comment: And how it will look in my code using copy or your other suggestions, i don't know how works code

Comment: `Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()`
`Dim x As Long`

`For x = 2 To 10`
`Range("C" & x) = Range("B" & x).Value * 10`
`Next x`

`End Sub`

Comment: Ok it works good, but how to multiply by a constant with input in textbox?

Comment: Try `* Textbox1.Value`